# How do I make applescript not wait for sound effect to finish?

Tags: applescript

I want my script to display a message and play a sound at the same time. Right now it plays the sound and then displays the message.

```
do shell script "afplay '/System/Library/Sounds/Morse.aiff'"
display dialog "Could not find contact: " & "\"" & victim & "\"" with icon stop
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` and discarding `stdout`

```
do shell script "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Morse.aiff >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Note: You don't need to warp the path in single quotes if the path doesn't contain spaces.